# Wordpress: Import data and files from other website

Tags: wordpress

from my site where I installed WordPress and I have the need to download data from a different site. The data is HTML portions of files in CSV format. The download site has an authentication information (http://app.condomani.it). I own a regular account and a password. Voleco understand how to make wordpress to run the LOGIN on the site and then download the data. I tried to use a "remote content shortcodes" plugin with this configuration:

```
[Url = remote_content "http://app.condomani.it/accedi?returl=http://app.condomani.it/adm/bilancio-preventivo" 
method = "POST" 
params = "idc = 13532; ide = 27235 "userpwd =" gait: xxx"htmlentities =" false "] [/ remote_content]
```

Does not work. Do you have any ideas for me?

Comment: you getting any error messages?

Comment: No. Nothing. It's seems that the POST method doesn't work at all. Are there other methots to make the trick?

Comment: you could make a widget that uses javascript to make the network call and extract the data as you need it. If you make your widget support a shortcode you can put it on the page pretty easily.